# iPhone application name on different stores

Tags: iphone, internationalization, itunes

Can an application have different names depending on the language of the store?

For example: 
Name of App in US store: AAAA
Name of App in other country store: BBBB

And the application icon, its possible to have different icons depending on the language of the store / user's iPhone?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can name your application differently for different languages, not stores. The difference is that some regions use the same language (USA and UK), and some regions use multiple languages (Canada).

You can also have different screenshots, descriptions and tags, but you can't have a different icon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
How I can do that? 

I have to edit my Localizable string and put specif strings that represent the application name? 

I have to change that on other configuration files?

Or I have to edit it in itunes connect? I found the place where your edit descriptions, tags, screenshots, but the field app name is locked.

Comment: @Rafael Localizable strings affect how app is looking on device (e.g. app name under icon). To add localization to app store you have to use iTunes Connect, there's an Add Localization button, but AFAIR you can add new localization and edit app name only when creating new version.

Comment: Ok, I will try it when I submit a new version. Thanks for the help!